# How to downgrade Composer via homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, development

My Composer updated to version 2 but I need to keep it running in version 1.

How could I downgrade my Composer via Homebrew since I don't see different formulas to version 1 and 2?

I already tried to run these commands below but it didn't work.

```
brew switch composer 1.10.15
brew install composer@1.10.15
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To check the versions available you can run this command:

```
brew log composer
```

[image: brew log composer]

Then install Composer and change the version directly via Composer command.

```
brew install composer
composer self-update 1.10.15
```

[To toggle between the 1.x and 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598028):

```
composer self-update --1
composer self-update --2
```